# removing whitespace in android Switch which is devoted to text

Tags: java, android, android-widget

(we all know) There are three parts in android Switch Widget  ... Text - Thumb - Track.
My question is how can we completely remove this text part if we don't want to use any text
because it's ruining the balance of the layout 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to not provide any text:

```
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use negative margin for the switch as follows and see if it works:

```
 <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp" />
```

I know some people consider it a bad practice to use negative margin but right it seems to be the easiest way.

You can set margin programmatically as well based on device type.

Comment: It is bad practice with a capital B !
But since we're talking android here I think we understand each other
Still ... since I'm going to support different screen sizes I cant use hardcoded margin