# Removing the Text Area from a Switch

Tags: android, textview, android-checkbox, android-compound-view

How can I remove text area fully from a Switch View ?
I do not want the text to take up any space in Switch.
Is there anything like View.GONE ?

I tried these properties and failed:

```
        android:text=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
```

I also checked this post but it wasn't helpful.
[Removing Whitespaces From Switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292103/removing-whitespace-in-android-switch-which-is-devoted-to-text)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, can you try ToggleButton instead? check this out. 
http://mirhoseini.com/how-to-create-a-toggle-button-with-custom-image-and-no-text-in-android/

Comment: I really wonder why switch view doesn't support this?